# Cannot add external VSTS NuGet Feed in Octopus

Tags: azure-devops, octopus-deploy, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to add an external NuGet feed to my VSTS source, but when I save & test the feed, I'm getting the following exception:

`NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://*********.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/QA/nuget/v3/index.json. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)`

When I enter the feed's URL into the browser and enter my personal access token, it authenticates fine...

`Octopus version 3.7.18`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted octopus support who have confirmed it is a bug:

https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/Issues/issues/3081

In the meantime, you can just use VSTS's V2 feed url which authenticates fine:

`https://<instance-name>.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/<feed-name>/nuget/v2`

Answer (score 0):

The error message means it is failed authorize.

Try to store the account information in NuGet.config by using this command:

```
nuget.exe sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username {anything} -password {your PAT}
```

Or

```
nuget.exe sources add -name {feed name} -source {feed URL} -username {username} -password {PAT} -StorePasswordInClearText
```

More information, you can refer to this article: [Authenticating to feeds with NuGet](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/nuget/auth)

Comment: hmm, not sure this possible in the context of Octopus?